# How to iterate through a list of ranges in Google Apps Script

Tags: list, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google sheet with many names and hours which need to be organized. I tried using built in functions, but this sheet is the result of other inputs on other sheets (so the length of the rows is variable)

```
Sheet 1

   A       B       C        D       E                     T       U    
Project| Name1 | Hours1 | Name2 | Hours2 | ... | ... | Name10 | Hours10|  
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
P1     | Larry | 10     | Bob   |  20    | ... | ... | Tim    | 10     |
P2     | Bob   | 15     | Tim   |  15    | ... | ... | Larry  | 15     | 
....   | ...   | ...    |  ...  | ...    | ... | ... | ...    | ...    | 
Pnth   | Tim   | 20     | Larry |  10    | ... | ... | Bob    | 10     |
```

So far I have tried to iterate through the whole sheet and used a list of names from which to sort with, but I need it to take on a variable length of rows.

```
function organize(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['B1:C','D1:E','F1:G','H1:I','J1:K','L1:M','N1:O','P1:Q','R1:S','T1:U']);
```

What I want it to look like (on a separate sheet): list of names and total hours

```
 Sheet 2

 Name | Total hours  | Number Projects Assigned|
 ——————————————————————————————————————————————
 Larry| TOTAL NUMBER |    4   (P1,P2,Pnth)     |
 Tim  | TOTAL NUMBER |    4   (P1,P2,Pnth)     |
 Bob  | TOTAL NUMBER |    4   (P1,P2,Pnth)     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Get all the values in the range
- Loop through them vertically and then horizontally
- Create a object with each name as key and [hours, projects] as value.
- Map the object back to a 2D array

#### Snippet:

```
function organize(values) {
  var out = {};//out object
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    for (var col = 1, l = row.length; col < l; col += 2) {
      var name = row[col];
      out[name] = out[name] || [0, 0]; //[hours,projects]
      out[name][0] += row[col + 1]; //hours sum
      out[name][1]++; //projects sum
    }
  });

  return Object.keys(out).map(function(name) {
    return [name, out[name][0], out[name][1]]; //[name, hours and projects]
  });
}
```

If used as a custom function,

```
=organize(A2:U4)
```

returns name, hours and projects.